# Databricks - nombre de columna = palabra reservada

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql, databricks

Tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: SELECT * FROM DataEnergy limit 20;]

Como se ve en la imagen la columna timestamp tengo fechas pero en formato string, por lo tanto quiero acceder a esa columna para transformarla a tipo date(primero quiero extraer la fecha sin la hora) pero al momento de acceder a la columna con la siguiente sentencia:

SELECT SPLIT(timestamp," ")[0] FROM DataEnergy;

Obtengo el mensaje:

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Column 'timestamp' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? []; line 1 pos 13;
'Project [unresolvedalias('SPLIT('timestamp,  )[0], None), 'FROM AS DataEnergy#131]
+- OneRowRelation

ya intenté colocando el campo entre [], tampoco me funciona.

Comment: y si mejor le cambias el nombre a algo que no sea una palabra reservada?